# \IfFileExists for global bibliography files

Tags: bibtex, texmf

I'm developing a document class which automatically loads the bibliography from Mendeley if available. Here is the code hooked to \end{document}:

```
\IfFileExists{library.bib}{
    \ClassWarningNoLine{imetex}{Mendeley bibliography found}
    \ifdefempty{\imetex@bibliography}{
        \renewcommand{\imetex@bibliography}{library}
    }{
        \ClassWarningNoLine{imetex}{Adding local references from \imetex@bibliography.bib}
        \let\mybib\imetex@bibliography
        \renewcommand{\imetex@bibliography}{\mybib,library}
    }
}{
    \ClassWarningNoLine{imetex}{Mendeley bibliography not found}
}
\ifdefempty{\imetex@bibliography}{
    \ClassWarningNoLine{imetex}{No bibliography found}
}{
    \bibliography{\imetex@bibliography}
}
```

But `\IfFileExists{library.bib}` is always returning false, even though the file is in `~/texmf/bibtex/bib/local`. If I try `\bibliography{library}`, BibTeX successfully  loads the library.

So what is the problem? `IfFileExists` does not search in the entire `texmf` tree but only in the `tex` tree? What would be an alternative?

Comment: What happens if `\IfFileExists` used for other files?

Comment: `.bib` files are bibtex input so not normally in the TEXINPUTS search path for input to latex.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It returns true for local folder bibliography files.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this explains why he can find the local folder bib files but not the global ones. Any workaround?

Comment: @Victor: David Carlisle answered the 'question' already, in my point of view. The local folder is always in the search path

Comment: @Victor  I suppose the canonical answer is just to use `\bibliography{library}` and leave warning about it not being there to the program that searches for the file, namely bibtex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess it would work, since BibTeX skip the file raising erros, but I wish I had not `Process exited with error(s)` so I won't scare users.

Answer (score 3):

`.bib` files are bibtex input so not normally in the TEXINPUTS search path for input to latex.

I think the best solution is to use

```
\bibliography{library}
```

and leave warning about it not being there to the program that searches for the file, namely bibtex.

Alternatives would be to require that TEXINPUTS is locally changed to include `$BIBINPUTS` so then `\IfFileExists` would work, or to use shell-escape feature 
and use an external call to `kpsewhich` to check if the file is there, but both of these make the class considerably harder to set up for your users.

Comment: I guess it would work, since BibTeX skip the file raising erros, but I wish I had not `Process exited with error(s)` so I won't scare users. If no one come up with a simple alternative I'll accept this as solution.